# overflow in exp(x) in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm using function: numpy.log(1+numpy.exp(z))

for small values of z (1-705) it gives identity result(1-705 {as expected}), 
but for larger value of z from 710+ it gives infinity, and throw error "runtimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp"

Comment: For all practical purposes, I'd say `log(1 + exp(705))` is approximately 705. The `+1` makes nearly no difference because `e^705` is just so huge. You can just catch the error and set the value to be equal to `z`.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but the problem is with exp(x), for larger value>709 it gives infinity @Praveen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For large *z* you could use

```
z + log(exp(-z) + 1)
```

which is mathematically but not numerically the same thing.

In code:

```
(z + np.log(np.exp(-z) + 1)) if z > 0 else np.log(1 + np.exp(z))
```

If you need a vectorised version:

```
np.maximum(z, 0) + np.log(np.exp(-np.absolute(z)) + 1)
```

As @Praveen points out there is a function `np.log1p` which calculates log(1+x) but is more accurate if |x| is small. I recommend using it in the above.

Comment: Consider using [`np.log1p`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html) instead of `np.log` to compute `np.log(np.exp(-z) + 1)`...

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are overflowing the register such that it is overwriting itself. You have exceeded the maximum value that can be stored in the register. You will need to use a different datatype that will most likely not be compatible with exp(.). You might need a custom function that works with 64-bit Integers.